# Why my FPS drop?

Tags: java, android, frame-rate

It drops only when object is clicked and needs to be removed from list.
Here is code:

```
if(event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN){
            for(Bottle bottle : new ArrayList<Bottle>(bottles)){
                if(bottle.position.dist(touchPoint) < 40 ){
                    bottles.remove(bottle);
                    if(bottle.type == Bottle.BOTTLE){
                        score+=10;
                        Assets.playSound(Assets.beeropenSound);
                    }
                    else if (bottle.type == Bottle.BOTTLE30){
                        score+=30;
                        Assets.playSound(Assets.beeropenSound);
                    }
                    else if (bottle.type == Bottle.GLASS_OF_BEER){
                        score+=5;
                        Assets.playSound(Assets.pourbeerSound);
                    }
                    else if (bottle.type == Bottle.WATER_BOTTLE){
                        score-=50;
                    }

                    // burping
                    if (score % 200 == 0 && score > 1){
                        Assets.playSound(Assets.burpSounds[burp]);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

, and here is fps log:

```
01-20 19:18:19.629: D/FPS(27501):  59
01-20 19:18:20.639: D/FPS(27501):  59
01-20 19:18:21.639: D/FPS(27501):  49
01-20 19:18:22.649: D/FPS(27501):  59
01-20 19:18:23.669: D/FPS(27501):  60
01-20 19:18:24.669: D/FPS(27501):  59
01-20 19:18:25.689: D/FPS(27501):  60
01-20 19:18:26.699: D/FPS(27501):  43
01-20 19:18:27.719: D/FPS(27501):  60
01-20 19:18:28.739: D/FPS(27501):  60
01-20 19:18:29.759: D/FPS(27501):  60
```

I tried removing this stuff but it is not it:

- Removing sound effects
- Remove streaming background music(3mb mp3 file)
- removing copy of ArrayList, iterating true bottles list and adding what should be removed to another list and remove that list from bottles list
- Assets.burpSounds[burp] : burp was local variable that was generated randomly with Random java mudle. I removed that (burp is in constructor) it didn't worked...

One thing is left - garbage collectors. 
Is it what makes my fps drops ?
How can I be sure ?
How to fight these enemies ?

And as I said before it **ONLY** drops when this block of code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the GC as well, I would add a flag on the bottles list that tells the object it is "removed" instead of actually removing it, thereby avoiding the gc.

Edit: Why are you creating a new arraylist on every touch? shouldn't it just be:

```
for( Bottle bottle : bottles ) {...}
```

Comment: But list is used 2 more times in update so I should add != null. I am trying different approach now : time based update...

Comment: Because I have to remove object from bottles and I can't remove it while iterating over it...

Comment: of course you can, you just have to remove it from the list after your score code